# Размесить на экране 9 блоков div. По клику на каждый блок он должен исчезать

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Не могу сделать чтобы по клику на div удалялся именно этот div на который нажал. Оно начинает удалять с последнего блока div и по порядку до самого верха а не тот блок на который нажимаешь. У меня не работает может есть другой способ а и кстати крестик желательно убрать просто сделать клик по блоку

```
    let child = document.querySelectorAll(".div");

for (let div of child) {
  div.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "afterbegin",
    '<button class="remove-div">[x]</button>'
  );
  div.onclick = () => div.remove();
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код в виде текста.

Comment: Вам в прошлом сообщении сказали, что бы вы не размещали код картинками. Замените картинки на код и уточните, что именно не получается?

Comment: @Flade, я просто добавил в твой пример сами ДИВы - пример получился рабочий.

Comment: @ksa это не правильно предлагать решение отредактировав вопрос. Откати свою правку лучше. Ведь у человека в этом и могла быть проблема, с html. Теперь этот вопрос больше не показывает вопрос человека, а показывает твоё решение.
Правильно будет предложить ответ с твоим кодом.
Я с самого начала и не понял, почему код в вопросе работает. Потом я посмотрел в историю изменений и только тогда понял, что это код не человека, задающего вопрос, а код того, кто решил ответить таким образом

Comment: @Михаил Камахин, уже вернули как было.

Answer (score 0):

Ты должен использовать делегирование событий. Для этого ты сначала должен добавить класс каждому div элементу с разными названиями. Про делегирование можешь прочитать тут https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Зачем добавлять каждому `div` класс? О.о

Answer (score 0):

Если делегирование для вас сложно в понимании, то <s>лучше разобраться</s> можете по event'у кликнутого элемента ([event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)), получать его родителя ([.parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)) и удалять его ([.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)).
К слову, это почти точно так же, как и при делегирование..

```js
let child = document.querySelectorAll("div");

for (let div of child) {
  div.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "afterbegin",
    '<button class="remove-div">[x]</button>'
  );
  div.onclick = (event) => event.target.parentElement.remove();
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
```

---

Вот вариант с [делегированием](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation):

```js
let removeBlock = document.querySelector('.remove');
let removeBlockItems = removeBlock.children;

for (let div of removeBlockItems) {
  div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<button class="remove-div">[x]</button>');
}

removeBlock.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if(event.target.classList.contains('remove-div')) {
    event.target.parentElement.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="remove">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```